# To retrieve the list items based on todays date

Tags: spfx-webparts

```
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import  './ThoughtforthedayWebPart.module.scss';
import * as strings from 'ThoughtforthedayWebPartStrings';

import MockHttpClient from './MockHttpClient';
import { 
  SPHttpClientResponse,
  SPHttpClient,
  SPHttpClientConfiguration, 
   ISPHttpClientOptions,
} from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import {  
  Environment,  
  EnvironmentType  
} from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
 import * as $ from 'jquery';
 import 'jquery';

export interface ISPLists {  
  value: ISPList[];  
} 

export interface ISPList {  
  Title: string;  
  Quote: string;  

} 


export default class ThoughtforthedayWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IThoughtforthedayWebPartStrings> {


  public _getListData() {
    var today = new Date();
    var Startdate = today.toISOString().substring(0, 10) + "T00:00:00.000Z";
    var Enddate = today.toISOString().substring(0, 10) + "T23:00:00.000Z";
    var filterQuery = "?$top=1&$filter=Created  le datetime'" + Enddate + "' and Created ge datetime'" + Startdate + "'";
    $.ajax({
       url: encodeURI(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Thoughtfortheday')/items" + filterQuery),
       type: "GET",
       headers: {
           "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
           "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
       },
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-function-expression
       success: function (data) {
          var allData = data.d.results;
          var datalen = data.d.results.length;
          if (datalen == 0) {
             console.log("No records available for today's date");
          }
          else {
             console.log("Available Record:", allData);
          }
       },
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-function-expression
       error: function (err) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
       }
    });
 }



  private _renderList(items: ISPList[]): void {  
    let html: string = '<table class="TFtable" border=1 width=100% style="border-collapse: collapse;">';  

    items.forEach((item: ISPList) => {  
      html += `  

        <div align="center">  ${item.Quote}</div>
          <div align="right"> ${'-'}  ${item.Title}</div> 

          `;  
    });  
    html += `</table>`;  
    const listContainer: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#spListContainer');  
    listContainer.innerHTML = html;  
  } 

  public render(): void {  
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `  
    <div class="thoughtfortheday}">  
  <div class="container">  
   <div class="ms-Grid-row ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white row}">  
     <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-u-lg10 ms-u-xl8 ms-u-xlPush2 ms-u-lgPush1">    
     </div>  
   </div>  
   <div class="ms-Grid-row ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white row}">  
   <div style="background-color:Black;color:white;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size:18px;">Thought for the day</div>  
   <br>  
  <div id="spListContainer" />  
   </div>  
  </div>  
  </div>`;  
  this._renderListAsync();  
  }
  public _renderListAsync() {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }



  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

This is my code please check and revert me back

Comment: please share what error you are getting?

Comment: your code is not making sense, what are you trying to do? _renderListAsync why it is through exception? why is _getListData never called?

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be like this:

```
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

import styles from './TestWebPart.module.scss';
import * as strings from 'TestWebPartStrings';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
export interface ITestWebPartProps {
  description: string;
}

export default class TestWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<ITestWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    this._getListData();
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <div class="${ styles.test}" id="tableData"></div>`;
  }


  public _getListData() {
    var today = new Date();
    var Startdate = today.toISOString().substring(0, 10) + "T00:00:00.000Z";
    var Enddate = today.toISOString().substring(0, 10) + "T23:00:00.000Z";
    var dynamicHtml = "<table border=1 width=100% style='border-collapse: collapse;'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th>"
    var filterQuery = "?$top=1&$filter=Created  le datetime'" + Enddate + "' and Created ge datetime'" + Startdate + "'";
    $.ajax({
      url: encodeURI(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('T1')/items" + filterQuery),
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      },
      success: function (data) {
        //in query top=1 so it will return only 1 value so will directly use [0] item
        var allData = data.d.results[0];
        var datalen = data.d.results.length;
        if (datalen == 0) {
          dynamicHtml += "<tr>";
          dynamicHtml += "<td  colspan='2' style='text-align: center;'>Record not found.</td>";
          dynamicHtml += "</tr>";
          dynamicHtml += "</table>";
          $("#tableData").html(dynamicHtml);
        }
        else {
          dynamicHtml += "<tr>";
          dynamicHtml += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + allData.ID + "</td>";
          dynamicHtml += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + allData.Title + "</td>";
          dynamicHtml += "</tr>";
          dynamicHtml += "</table>";
          $("#tableData").html(dynamicHtml);
        }
      },
      error: function (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      }
    })
  }



  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

If record is available then output like this:
[image: Found Image]

If record is not available then output like this:
[image: Not Found Image]

Regards,
Chandani Prajapati